# ASP.Net MVC Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have defined MVC controller in my MVC web application. I have 5 different action names defined in the controller. All actions are doing different things.

What i want to do is defined a common MVC route in global.asax instead of 5 different MVC routes. One route i have defined like this in global.asax file.

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "Action1/1", // Route name
           "xyz/check-data1", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "CheckDate", action = "Check1" } // Parameter defaults
       );
```

I need 5 different routes here because these 5 different routes will be called 5 hyperlinks in my web page.

I do not want to do copy and paste above route and create 5 different routes.
For e.g. one more route i can defined like this as below.

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "Action2/2", // Route name
           "xyz/check-data2", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "CheckDate", action = "Check2" } // Parameter defaults
       );
```

Please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 2):

The typical pattern is to standardize your actions so that they can work with the default route:

```
/{Controller}/{Action}/{id?}
```

If you're not going to use standard actions, then you have no choice but to specify your routes individually and manually.

However, there's a nuget package called [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/) that lets you specify the routes on the actions, themselves, using an attribute. This is often easier and more fluid if you're going to be dealing with a lot of custom routes.